# Can you vs. Do you think you can

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Is there a right or wrong way to ask someone to do something? The other day I said to my husband, "Do you think you can fax this paper for me?" He said that was insulting and I should say "Can you fax this paper for me?"  Thoughts??

Comment: Technically, *can* you fax this paper is still questioning his ability to do something. I think you were polite (and not overly so) in the way you asked. People often use *"Do you think you can"* instead of *"please"*. *Would you please...* or *would you mind...* might strike him as more appropriate perhaps.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I tend to agree: for simple tasks in which the questioner already knows the answer "Do you think [that] ... ?" may come across as patronising or passive-aggressive. It is positively insulting in such use as *"Do you think you could get up off your backside and actually do some work?"*

Answer (score 4):

A- "Do you think " is used for asking someone **politely to do** something.

E.g.:

Do you think you could pass me my bag?

Do you think you can fax this paper for me?.... is ***not impolite or insulting.***

B- "Do you think " is used for asking **someone's opinion**

E.g.

Do you think we'll get this finished on time?

**And why not keep the request simple and pleasing to the ear**.

Please, can you fax....

Can you fax...please.

Comment: If you get too polite, you risk people will see it as sarcasm - and honestly, I would not take lightly to someone expressing doubts about my ability to use a fax-machine.

Comment: yes, you may be right. "Too humble is half proud.

Comment: 'Do you think you could ...' is acceptable as a polite form, but context and delivery are, as ever, important. 'Would you ... please?' is perhaps safest.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that "do you think" for such trivial tasks is patronising, and the natural answer is "of course I can but do you want me to?" My sister is guilty of using this with me and I tell her everytime, just say "please can you...". That is soooo much better.